# Strange error in iAd

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad

I've added iAd to my application, and while testing it in my simulator/device I receive some error from `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:`, here are the error listed:

`MyTest[11915:907] [iAd] Error di=3: The operation couldn’t be completed. Inventario annunci non disponibile`

`MyTestApp[11877:907] [iAd] Error di=4: The operation couldn’t be completed. L'applicazione presenta un errore di configurazione rete di iAd`

`2013-01-15 02:31:26.620 MyTestApp[11877:907] [iAd] Error di=5: The operation couldn’t be completed. Il banner è visibile ma non ha contenuto`

After some time (30-40sec) the banner correctly show in the device.. I am missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Does your app crash when the Error Comes...

Comment: Are you testing your app in the Simulater (Try your app in an real device if you are).

Comment: No, the app doesn't crash, and I'm testing in both, device and simulator..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple documentation says: "While you are developing your application, iAd Network sends test advertisements to your application. To assist you in validating your implementation, the iAd Network occasionally returns errors to test your error handling code."
Also in my app iad return a mix of correct banner,error 3,error 5... 
I think that this problem will disapper after the release of the app when iAd will change from "iAd Network serves test ads" to "iAd Network serves live ads if you signed the iAd Network Agreement and enabled advertising for your application"